# Where do I run a Java Rich Internet Application on google cloud?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-compute-engine

So, I have a script that I am fairly sure is an RIA, but I'm not 100% sure.

Here is the file structure:

```
bin
conf
jvm
lib
logs
resources
xml
digest.txt
getdown.txt
theimporter.jar
proxy.txt
release_notes.txt
version.txt
```

In the conf folder, there is theimporter.client.properties, theimporter.properties, log.properties, and log4j.properties  file

Anyways, in the bin folder, there is a run.sh file. All I want to do is execute run.sh on a cron.

What would I use in the google cloud to run this script?

I know I can make it work on compute engine, however I am wondering if there is a better solution.

Should I use App Engine? If so, how exactly would I structure it inside of the App Engine?

If I should use Compute Engine, what would be the bare minimum on need on this server? Would I just need to install Linux and run the .sh on a cron from there?

Cloud computer seems almost unnecessary, because this would require me to keep linux up to date, etc. I was leaning toward App Engine, but I am sort of baffled as to how to implement this, and if App Engine would even support this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compute Engine is probably your best bet here. You might start with the smallest instance possible at first (`f1-micro`) while you test out your app.

App Engine, at least the standard environment, very likely won't work for you without writing new code. The flexible environment might work, but I think until you've tested your app and know how to run it, Compute Engine is likely your best starting point.